# ReactJS: "TypeError: Object(...)(...) is undefined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the code below:

```js
handleImageChange = (newFile, crop) => {
    var string = RandomString.generate(20);

    newImage(string, newFile, this.state.type, 0)
    .then((result) => {
      if(result) {
        this.toggleModal();
      }
    });
}

saveCropped() {
  var values = this.cropper.values();
  var crop = this.cropper.crop();
  var newFile = convertBase64ToFile(crop);

  setTimeout(function() {
    this.handleImageChange(newFile, crop);
  }.bind(this), 5000);
}
```

The function called is `saveCropped()` which then calls the `handleImageChange` function.

What this function does (newImage) is send an Axios request to my server, but when I run it I get the following error: "TypeError: Object(...)(...) is undefined"

The thing is, even tho I'm getting this error, the code executes in the background with no problem i.e. the request is sent to my server and I get a response in the console.

The error points to line 5 `(newImage(...))`.

The newImage function works because this is not the only place where its called and the function only returns a boolean; even so here it is:

```js
function newImage(image_ID, image, imgType, type) {
    var url = ...;

    const header = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': imgType
      }
    };

    axios.post(url, image, header)
    .then(function (response) {
      if(response.status === 200) {
        if(type !== '1')
          sessionStorage.setItem('avatar', image_ID);
        console.log("Image uploaded!");
        return true;
      }
      else
        return false;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(`Image could not be uploaded due to:\n${error}`);
      return false;
    });
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why are you storing a ref to `this` when you pass an arrow function to `.then`? What is the definition of `newImage`? What line in the source does the error point to?

Comment: @JaredSmith I was storing a ref to `this` by mistake. The previous version of the function wasn't an arrow function. newImage represents another function in a diferent file that does the request: `function newImage(image_ID, image, imgType, type) {...}` And the error occurs in line 5 `newImage(...)`

Comment: I don't see `newImage` defined anywhere in the code you've shared with us. What makes you think it should be anything other than undefined? Show us a [mcve].

Comment: @JaredSmith But the `newImage` function is called and executes properly due to the fact that I have a `console.log` if the function gets a 200OK

Comment: Please show full code including the `newImage()` function.

Comment: @JohnKennedy Done. My bad

Comment: @Quentin The function is imported properly from another file and used in other functions (which work as intended)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are trying to call `then()` on the return value of `newImage()` … but that function **doesn't have a return statement**.

Presumably, you want to return the promise returned by calling `axios.post`:

```
return axios.post(url, image, header).
    etc etc
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this *particular* bug has been solved. But it's probably worth noting for future searchers; I received this error, and it turned out to be because of a configuration object had two commas in a row like so:

```js
{
  name: "Something"
},,{
  name: "Foobar"
}
```