# TypeError: Object(...)(...) is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm trying to use the logout function from the AuthContextProvider component

 this is the code

```
import { AuthContext } from '../../../context/authContext.js';
import { useContext } from 'react';

  const {logout} = useContext(AuthContext);
  const history = useHistory();
  const onClick = async () => {
    try{
     await logout();
      history.push('/');
      }catch(err){
        console.log(err);
      }
  }
```

but I keep getting this error

```
    TypeError: Object(...)(...) is undefined
SignOut
C:/.../views/sub-pages/SignOut.js:10

   7 | const SignOut = ({ show, closeModal }) => {
   8 | 
   9 | 
> 10 |  const {logout} = useContext(AuthContext);
     | ^  11 |  const history = useHistory();
  12 |  const onClick = async () => {
  13 |    try{
```

And this is the logout function code in the AuthContextProvider component

```
const logout = async (inputs) => {
 await axios.post("/auth/logout", inputs);
    setCurrentUser(null);
 }
```

I don't have a clue why it's giving me this error

Comment: You need to create a context (`React.createContext(...)`).

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of [ReactJS: "TypeError: Object(...)(...) is undefined"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50607760/reactjs-typeerror-object-is-undefined). Essentially, you need to return the value from `axios.post` in `logout`.

Comment: Actually... I might be entirely wrong on that. Apologies if so. Saw a similarity between the two, but I don't actually see how that would lead to this particular problem.